# How to copy Pyramid project?

Tags: pyramid, python-venv

How can I copy Pyramid project to another computer? I was following Pyramid's tutorial [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html) and finished first four chapters. I wasn't home so I copied directory with my project to my laptop to be able to go through it. I opened directory with VSCode, it automatically opened virtual environment that was installed (with `python3 -m venv env`). I tried few commands but got error:

```
bash: env/bin/pip: /home/user/path/to/project/env/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This got me thinking, how am I supposed to copy my project to another machine? Obviously, simple copying of directory doesn't work (because of virtual environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual environments are not relocatable. Recreate your virtual environment from scratch.